# Sublime Linter Path issue can't find flake 8 (probably due to using Pyenv

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I installed Sublime Linter and the Sublime Linter Plugin Using Package Control and installed Flake8 using pip.

I am using pyenv to manage my Python installs.

When installing flake 8 I get this message:

```
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: /Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/include/python3.9/UNKNOWN
sysconfig: /Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/include/python3.9
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
Requirement already satisfied: flake8 in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flake8) (0.6.1)
Collecting pyflakes<2.4.0,>=2.3.0
  Using cached pyflakes-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (68 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pycodestyle<2.8.0,>=2.7.0 in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flake8) (2.7.0)
Installing collected packages: pyflakes
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: /Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/include/python3.9/UNKNOWN
sysconfig: /Users/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/include/python3.9
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
Successfully installed pyflakes-2.3.1
```

And the path is here:

```
➜  ~ which flake8
/Users/<user>/.pyenv/shims/flake8
```

How do I point SublimeLinter to the pyenv install of flake8?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install the [`sublimeLinter-flake8`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-flake8) plugin, and follow the installation instructions. The settings (available at **`Sublime Text → Preferences → Package Settings → SublimeLinter`** on Mac) are pretty self-explanatory. Customize your user settings to include flake8 and any options you want to send to it. Set the `paths:osx` key to `"/Users/<user>/.pyenv/shims"`, and the `linters:flake8:python` setting to the full path to your `python` or `python3` binary in your virtualenv. Make sure you read through all the settings carefully so you know exactly what you want to customize. Documentation is also available [here](http://sublimelinter.com/en/latest).